# why ninja build and msbuild are unable to utilize more than roughly 50%?

Tags: msbuild, windows-10, ninja

I have a Lenovo Z51-70 laptop (Windows10). it had 8GB RAM by default and SSHD. When I used to compile large projects 20K c++ files Task Manager always showed 90-100% CPU utilization. A week back I upgraded SSHD to SSD and 8GB RAM to 16GB RAM for gaining speed in the compilation. But build time hasn't improved (it is almost same) but Task Manager always shows roughly 50% CPU utilization. Why it is not able to utilize anyway near 90-100%? and why same build on SSHD & 8GB RAM always used to consume roughly 90-100% CPU utilization? It is not specific to a particular build system, i have tried MSBUILD, NINJA. All build system show same CPU utilization. I have tried to compile different projects for excluding any reason which may be the project-specific.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you do a fresh install? Did you install the correct Intel Thermal Drivers and Lenovo power plans?

Comment: How is the memory module config? 1x 16GB? 2x 8GB? Official modules or 3rd party? What does CPU-Z report as DRAM freq and NB freq?